# Pivot Double Click - Show Detail event

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

Is there any way I can capture the Pivot Double Click event ? (The event which generates Detail View on another sheet.)

Is there any way I can see the whole datasource of selected pivot as a datatable ?

I am using C#, VSTO programming.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you'd do it in vba.  Put this code in the worksheet's code module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim pt As Excel.PivotTable

On Error Resume Next
Set pt = Target.PivotTable
If Err.Number = 0 Then
    MsgBox "captured"
    'to cancel uncomment next line
    'Cancel = True
End If
End Sub
```

EDIT: "I am looking for after double click event, as I need to capture the range of values on new sheet."

Try this then.  Put it in the ThisWorkbook module.  It uses a module-level variable to track whether the pivot was double-clicked and checks it in the NewSheet event.

```
Private PivotDoubleClicked As Boolean

Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim pt As Excel.PivotTable
On Error Resume Next
Set pt = Target.PivotTable
If Err.Number = 0 Then
    PivotDoubleClicked = True
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
If PivotDoubleClicked Then
    MsgBox "new sheet from pivot double-click"
    PivotDoubleClicked = False
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I am looking for after double click event, as I need to capture the range of values on new sheet, or best if I can get whole data source as data table from pivot object.

Comment: Yes. But above solution will make me have two sheet level events. The events will be there whenever there is a double click on sheet or a new sheet is added irrespective of a pivot double click. If possible, I would like to avoid declaring those events.

Comment: What is your concern about having the two events?  What I've laid out is a standard type of approach to these types of situations.  You can narrow it down by checking the sheet before checking if it's a pivot cell.  It's easy to say "Yes, but" after you've got an answer, but not as easy to guess your requirements before you list them. :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're interested in the `Range` object's [`ShowDetail`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.showdetail%28v=office.11%29) property.

To get the entire dataset, you can set this property for the [`DataBodyRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa168512%28v=office.11%29.aspx) of the pivot table.

```
Excel.PivotTable pivotTable = (Excel.PivotTable)Globals.Sheet3.PivotTables(1);
pivotTable.DataBodyRange.ShowDetail = true;
```

---

**Edit**: Per comment, if you want the dataset that the pivot table renders, you'd have to write a method that uses the `PivotCache` to determine the `SourceType` and get the data in reverse depending on the type of `SourceType`. There's no property of `PivotTable` or `PivotCache` that returns a `ADODB.RecordSet` regardless of the `SourceType`, much less a .NET `DataTable`.

Comment: Right. I am interested in entire data set,but setting the property true won't give me the dataset in an object. I want to capture the dataset without any effects on workbook/worksheet.